# Angularjs querySelector find element based on property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-selectors

I tried to find if angularjs can do like below:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('.content-here').find('div.offsetTop=8');
```

Can someone help me? You can see my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kVxzVnOuP2uA89rlfmYZ?p=preview) here.

Comment: what do you want to find in your plunker? there is no `div` with class `offsetTop` in your plunker. there's a text node with content that contains `{"localName":"div","offsetTop":8}`. did you intend to create DOM nodes based on the enries of  `$scope.show` array?

Comment: I want to allocate class `animated fadeInLeft` in each element with different respective delays. `$scope.show` just show the property I got from my variable `elementObj`. Are you clear? Sorry for bad english.

Comment: _in each element_ - what element?

Comment: All elements contained in `.content-here` class. In my case all the divs including image.

Comment: `angular.element(document.querySelector('.content-here'))[0]`will work for you.

Comment: @candidJ not working..can you show me? I tried but did not work.

Comment: `angular.element(document.querySelector('.content-here')).find('*').addClass('animated tada');` works. adds animation to all

Comment: I did it before ...Now I want to specific to each property..for my case based on `offsetTop`. The reason is I need call each element one by one is to put class `animated tada` with respective delays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:
You could make a directive if you do not wish to specify one by one. Also, remove the unecessary code in the controller.
[Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/OWiAy0GtZvl37XeiZ9OI?p=preview)

```
  .directive('animateFromLeft', function($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
          var children = elem.children();
          children.addClass('animated fadeInLeft');

          var animationDelay = 0;
          for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            children[i].style.animationDelay = animationDelay.toString() + 's';
            animationDelay += 1;
          }

          $compile(elem)(scope);
        }
      };
    });
```

========================================================================

I think you are doing it in hard way. I assume that you will not be using ng-repeat and based on your scenario you can specific the animation delay one by one.

[Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/iuUh1Xj3lfR9jaM7sw1t?p=preview)

```
<div class="content-here">
      <div class="animated fadeInLeft" style="animation-delay: 0s">1</div>
      <div class="animated fadeInLeft" style="animation-delay: 1s">2</div>
      <img class="animated fadeInLeft" style="animation-delay: 2s" width="100px" src="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/110/images/74627-0-1459502036.jpg" />
      <div class="animated fadeInLeft" style="animation-delay: 3s">3</div>
      <div class="animated fadeInLeft" style="animation-delay: 4s">4</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to use that way since I did not want to add manually the class. Let the querySelector find and addClass from there.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much for your nice codes!.